# Search engines will only index links in your sitemap for the current URL level and below? Still True?

Tags: python, django, sitemap

According to django documentation:

> Search engines will only index links in your sitemap for the current
>   URL level and below.

Taken from here
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/sitemaps/

Is this actually true because I see many people using packages such as django-staticsitemaps which serves the sitemap from say /static/sitemap.xml. According to the quote above that would mean search engines will only look at the urls in the sitemap that are below /static/

Answer (score 0):

True, according to the [sitemap protocol site](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html). 
Search for the **Sitemap file location** section on that page for details.

Comment: Ok so it seems that it is true, and all the people who are serving their sitemap from the static directory are doing it wrong UNLESS they change their robots.txt file and point to location of the sitemap file location? Or is it not technically a cross submit?

Comment: I don't think that's a cross submit since it's not on different hosts. It could still be theoretically OK if everything they want to serve is also under the static dir (not very likely, tho).